# How to write an Assert statement for collection in Xunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm using an xUnit test framework to write some unit test.  Below is a code snippet which test if `azColumns` collection is empty or not.  However, I was thinking is there a better way to assert `azColumns` collection without using two `Assert` inside an `if..else` block statement?

Maybe a one liner `Assert` statement that makes sense?

```
private static string LoadJsonFile()
{
    const string fileName = "templateFileContent_1.json";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $@"Data\{fileName}");

    return !File.Exists(filePath) ? string.Empty : filePath;
}

private static string GetJsonData()
{
    JObject jsonObject;
    var jsonFile = LoadJsonFile();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonFile)) return string.Empty;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
    {
        var jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    }

    return jsonObject.ToString();
}

private static JObject GetBaseConfigurationObject()
{
    var json = GetJsonData();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) return null;

    var baseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
    return baseObject;
}

[Fact]
public void ExportColumns_Should_Not_Be_Empty_Or_Null()
{
    // Arrange
    IEnumerable<az_Columns> azColumns = null;

    // Act
    var baseConfig = GetBaseConfigurationObject();
    var fileContent = baseConfig?["templateFileContent"];

    if (fileContent != null)
    {
        var baseConfiguration = fileContent.ToObject<BaseConfiguration>();
        azColumns = baseConfiguration?.ExportData?.az_Columns;
    }

    // Assert
    if (azColumns == null)
    {
        Assert.Null(azColumns);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.NotEmpty(azColumns);
    }
}
```

Any inputs is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is usually done with two tests, one test where you expect `azColumns` to be null, and one test where you expect `azColumns` to not be empty. When unit testing you want to make sure you're testing one condition that has one result.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for your comment. I agree, it can be separated with two unit tests with its respective result.  But, I'm keen to know if `Assert` has the functionality to verify two different results in one statement call?  Sorry for being noob here, just started out to write some unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If interested in using [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) you can assert as follows

```
[Fact]
public void ExportColumns_Should_Not_Be_Empty_Or_Null() {
    //Arrange
    //...omitted for brevity

    //Act
    //..omitted for brevity

    //Assert
    azColumns.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
}
```

After exercising your test you are asserting that the collection should not be null or empty. If it is null or empty the test will fail otherwise it will pass as expected.

Comment: for sure this line `azColumns.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty()` will throw an exception.  Could you please elaborate your answer mate?

Comment: @Juniuz Your test is named `ExportColumns_Should_Not_Be_Empty_Or_Null()`. After exercising your test you are asserting that the collection is not null or empty. if it is null or empty the test will fail otherwise it will pass as expected.

Comment: thanks for that.  I didn't know this Fluent Assertions, I think this is the one that I need.